# Return only few elements of numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array in the below format. how can I slice the array so that I only get 1's in it.

```
array([[1, 2, 1, ..., 2, 2, 2],
       [1, 1, 1, ..., 2, 2, 2],
       [1, 1, 1, ..., 2, 2, 2],
       ...,
       [1, 1, 1, ..., 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, ..., 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, ..., 1, 1, 1]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume your array name is a.

```
a = a[np.where(a == 1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.

```
for a in array:
   if a == 1:
     print(a)
```

And if you want to store the values (not print them) try something like this.

```
ab = [1, 2, 1, ..., 2, 2, 2]
    
numberList = []
        
def numbers(array):
  for a in array:
    if a == 1:
     numberList.append(a)
            
numbers(ab)
print(numberList)
```